# Filter columns with missing above threshold in spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I want to filter all the columns with missing values above 90 pct in spark so I can remove them from analysis.

I tried the following code, but it takes forever:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import isnull, when, count, col
total_rows = df.count()
features_missing_above_90 = []
    
for feature in df.columns:
    
    feature_nulls = df.filter(df[feature].isNull()).count()
    result = (feature_nulls/total_rows)
    
    if(result>0.9):
        features_missing_above_90.append(df[feature].str)
    
print(features_missing_above_90)
```

Can anyone help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `df.count()` to float value, without this your if condition will not execute as integer/integer will give you only integer.

```
>>> total_rows = float(df.count())
```

```
>>> features_missing_above_90 = []
```

```
>>> for feature in df.columns:
...     feature_nulls = df.filter(F.col(feature).isNull()).count()
...     result = feature_nulls/total_rows
...     if(result>0.7):
...             features_missing_above_90.append(feature)
...
```

```
>>> print(features_missing_above_90)
['b', 'e']
```

You can also try below code.

```
>>> df.show()
+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|   a|   b|   c|   d|   e|   f|
+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|   1|null|   2|   3|null|   4|
|   2|null|null|   5|null|   6|
|   4|   2|   1|   4|   5|   6|
|   5|null|null|null|null|   4|
|null|null|null|null|null|null|
+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

```
>>> threshold = 0.7
```

Applying Logic

```
>>> columns = map(lambda c: F.when(((F.count(F.col("*")) - F.size(F.collect_set(F.col(c))))/F.count(F.col("*"))) > F.lit(threshold), F.lit(c)),df.columns)
```

```
>>> df \
... .select(F.array(*columns).alias("columns")) \
... .select(F.explode(F.col("columns")).alias("columns")) \
... .select(F.collect_set(F.col("columns")).alias("missing")) \
... .collect()[0]

Row(missing=[u'b', u'e'])
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your post. Maybe would be better to use _collect_list_ instead of _collect_set_ in the map function to deal with categorical fields that have repeated values, considering that _collect_set_ ignores duplicates.

Comment: Ok,Accessing duplicate columns are difficult.. if you have duplicate columns in dataframe say columns names a, a .. how will get values only second a column..?

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant to append the column name to the list, not the string representation of the dataframe.

```
total_rows = df.count()
features_missing_above_90 = []
    
for feature in df.columns:    
    feature_nulls = df.filter(df[feature].isNull()).count()
    result = (feature_nulls / total_rows)
    
    if (result > 0.9):
        features_missing_above_90.append(feature)
    
df = df.select([col for col in df.columns if col not in features_missing_above_90])
```

Answer (score 0):

After analyzing the code by @Srinivas, I did some minor modifications for performance purposes:

`threshold = 0.9

columns = map(lambda c: F.when(   ((F.sum(F.col(c).isNull().cast("double"))) / (F.count("*")))    >= F.lit(threshold), F.lit(c)),df.columns)

lst_columns_missing = df \
    .select(F.array(*columns).alias("columns")) \
    .select(F.explode(F.col("columns")).alias("columns")) \
    .select(F.collect_set(F.col("columns")).alias("missing")) \
    .collect()[0]`